# AWS CodeDeploy - The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to setup Codedeploy with Github but keep getting:

```
The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed 
deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some 
instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: 
HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)
```

Upon checking /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log on the server, it has the following error:

```
 2017-12-13 10:15:34 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(25805)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Cannot reach InstanceService: Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::UnrecognizedClientException - The security token included in the request is invalid. 2017-12-13 10:15:42 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(25805)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1352_rpm. 2017-12-13 10:15:44 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(25805)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 400 2.152917 3 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-2:971219192778:instance/xxx") Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Errors::UnrecognizedClientException The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I am more of a front end developer, so do not know where to look to debug. Based on the AWS [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-github.html), tried to setup one of my github projects to work with AWS EC2 Codedeploy.

Based on the online suggestions, I have checked the credentials (~/.aws/credentials), everything seems fine.

If you could please advise me further on what to try or how to get to the root of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?